# Coluring row based on condition in List view

Tags: android

I haved filled the list view using setAdapter as given below

```
cursor = manifest_helper.GetDeliveriesAgainstManifest(pkManifest);





    cursor.moveToFirst();

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Deliv_Address",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Address")));
        map.put("Deliv_Time",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Time")));
        map.put("Deliv_Order",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DeliveryOrder")));
        map.put("Deliv_IsCustomerPickup",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("IsCustomerPickup")));
        map.put("Deliv_FKDeliveryStatus",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FKDeliveryStatus")));
        map.put("Deliv_PKDelivery",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PKDelivery")));
        alist.add(map);
        cursor.moveToNext();


    }
    sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, alist, R.layout.deliveries_list_row,
            new String[] { "Deliv_Address", "Deliv_Time",
                    "Deliv_Order", "Deliv_IsCustomerPickup",
                    "Deliv_FKDeliveryStatus", "Deliv_PKDelivery" },
            new int[] { R.id.tv_Deliv_Address, R.id.tv_Deliv_Time,
                    R.id.tv_Deliv_Order,
                    R.id.tv_Deliv_IsCustomerPickup,
                    R.id.tv_Deliv_FKDeliveryStatus,
                    R.id.tv_Deliv_PKDelivery });
    //selectedAdapter = new SelectedAdapter(this, 0, alist);
    //selectedAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

    ListDeliveries.setAdapter(sd);
```

The Problem is that i have a field "IsCustomerPickup" which have value either C or O.
Me want to differentiate each  rows by means of different color....will anyone help me...pls...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extend SimpleAdapter into your own CustomAdapter class that is able to read the isCustomerPickup value and set the rowView background accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using a custom adapter for your listview. There are endless tutorials on how to do this on the web. e.g: [Android Series: Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this will work with a Simpel Adapter. 
I think you have to write your on custom adapter and make your own listitem layout. 
As root of a listitem take a linear layout. 
Make your own adapter an override the getView() Method.

Here are some snippets: 
create a listview in your layout file.
then make a 
custom_listview_row.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_root_listview_row"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_listview_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your row text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Write your activity with the listview and set your own adapter to the listview. Your adapter could look like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public MyListViewAdapter(Activity activity){
        mActivity = activity;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(mActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO OVERRIDE METHOD WITH YOUR DATABASE
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO OVERRIDE METHOD WITH YOUR DATABASE
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO OVERRIDE METHOD WITH YOUR DATABASE
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView rowTextView;
        public LinearLayout rowLinearLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        //If the view was never instantiated 
        if(convertView == null){
            vi = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_row.xml, null);
            holder.rowTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_listview_row);
            holder.rowLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.ll_root_listview_row);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder=(ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        /*
         * Here is your code to check which color the row should have
         * you can call it like 
         * if( /*row at position should be blue*) {
         * 
         *      holder.rowLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.blue);
         * }
         * 
         */


        return vi;
    }

}
```

I've not testet this Adapter but i think you can work with it and adapt it to your needs.

Hope this helps.